# installation error: cannot import name 'collections_abc' from 'six.moves' (unknown location)

Tags: python

I tried to `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]` on anaconda command promt

but got this errors while installing

```
ERROR: astroid 2.3.1 requires typed-ast<1.5,>=1.4.0; implementation_name == "cpython" and python_version < "3.8", which is not installed.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.1 has requirement six==1.12, but you'll have six 1.15.0 which is incompatible.
```

when I run it on jupyter notebook I get
`ImportError: cannot import name 'collections_abc' from 'six.moves' (unknown location)`

Comment: its becouse are you using python 3.8 and you need to use 3.7

Comment: Just `pip uninstall six` before installing `google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by explicitly installing an updated version of six (1.13.0 instead of 1.11.0) via:

```
pip3 install --upgrade six>=1.13.0
```

Answer (score -1):

As the error message suggests try downgrading the "six" version to 1.12, it should work. I was facing the same issue and downgrading the same worked for me.